system ID mismatch, node belongs to a different cluster
I have etcd cluster, and now trying to initialize patroni (on server A and server B), but whenever I try to do so I'm getting the error about cluster mismatch. Tried removing 'initialize' from etcd, tried completely clearing up etcd saved configuration, but none worked
So if I will start patroni on server A, it will successfully initialize, but if I will run it on server B, it will fail with that error. The first who initializes wins, I could say

Patroni on server A (B has the same but with different placement of addresses):
scope: postgres-cluster
name: vb-psql2
namespace: /service/

restapi:
  listen: 192.168.8.141:8008
  connect_address: 192.168.8.141:8008
  authentication:
    username: patroni
    password: '*'

etcd:
  hosts: 192.168.8.141:2379,192.168.8.164:2379

bootstrap:
  method: initdb
  dcs:
    ttl: 60
    loop_wait: 10
    retry_timeout: 27
    maximum_lag_on_failover: 2048576
    master_start_timeout: 300
    synchronous_mode: true
    synchronous_mode_strict: false
    synchronous_node_count: 1
    # standby_cluster:
      # host: 127.0.0.1
      # port: 1111
      # primary_slot_name: patroni
    postgresql:
      use_pg_rewind: false
      use_slots: true
      parameters:
        max_connections: 800
        superuser_reserved_connections: 5
        max_locks_per_transaction: 64
        max_prepared_transactions: 0
        huge_pages: try
        shared_buffers: 512MB
        work_mem: 128MB
        maintenance_work_mem: 256MB
        effective_cache_size: 4GB
        checkpoint_timeout: 15min
        checkpoint_completion_target: 0.9
        min_wal_size: 2GB
        max_wal_size: 4GB
        wal_buffers: 32MB
        default_statistics_target: 1000
        seq_page_cost: 1
        random_page_cost: 4
        effective_io_concurrency: 2
        synchronous_commit: on
        autovacuum: on
        autovacuum_max_workers: 5
        autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor: 0.01
        autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor: 0.02
        autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit: 200
        autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay: 20
        autovacuum_naptime: 1s
        max_files_per_process: 4096
        archive_mode: on
        archive_timeout: 1800s
        archive_command: cd .
        wal_level: replica
        wal_keep_segments: 130
        max_wal_senders: 10
        max_replication_slots: 10
        hot_standby: on
        hot_standby_feedback: True
        wal_log_hints: on
        shared_preload_libraries: pg_stat_statements,auto_explain
        pg_stat_statements.max: 10000
        pg_stat_statements.track: all
        pg_stat_statements.save: off
        auto_explain.log_min_duration: 10s
        auto_explain.log_analyze: true
        auto_explain.log_buffers: true
        auto_explain.log_timing: false
        auto_explain.log_triggers: true
        auto_explain.log_verbose: true
        auto_explain.log_nested_statements: true
        track_io_timing: on
        log_lock_waits: on
        log_temp_files: 0
        track_activities: on
        track_counts: on
        track_functions: all
        log_checkpoints: on
        logging_collector: on
        log_statement: mod
        log_truncate_on_rotation: on
        log_rotation_age: 1d
        log_rotation_size: 0
        log_line_prefix: '%m [%p] %q%u@%d '
        log_filename: 'postgresql-%a.log'
        log_directory: /var/log/postgresql

  initdb:  # List options to be passed on to initdb
    - encoding: UTF8
    - data-checksums

  pg_hba:
    - host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
    - host replication replicator 127.0.0.1/32 md5
    - host replication replicator 10.0.2.0/24 md5

postgresql:
  listen: 192.168.8.141,127.0.0.1:5432
  connect_address: 192.168.8.141:5432
  use_unix_socket: true
  data_dir: /var/lib/postgresql/11/main
  bin_dir: /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin
  config_dir: /etc/postgresql/11/main
  pgpass: /var/lib/postgresql/.pgpass_patroni
  authentication:
    replication:
      username: replicator
      password: ****
    superuser:
      username: postgres
      password: ****
  parameters:
    unix_socket_directories: /var/run/postgresql
    stats_temp_directory: /var/lib/pgsql_stats_tmp

  remove_data_directory_on_rewind_failure: false
  remove_data_directory_on_diverged_timelines: false

#  callbacks:
#    on_start:
#    on_stop:
#    on_restart:
#    on_reload:
#    on_role_change:

  create_replica_methods:
    - basebackup
  basebackup:
    max-rate: '100M'
    checkpoint: 'fast'

watchdog:
  mode: off  # Allowed values: off, automatic, required
  device: /dev/watchdog
  safety_margin: 5

tags:
  nofailover: false
  noloadbalance: false
  clonefrom: false
  nosync: false

  # specify a node to replicate from (cascading replication)
#  replicatefrom: (node name)


etcd:
ETCD_NAME="etcd2"
ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS="http://192.168.8.141:2379,http://127.0.0.1:2379"
ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS="http://192.168.8.141:2379"
ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS="http://192.168.8.141:2380"
ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS="http://192.168.8.141:2380"
ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TOKEN="etcd-postgres-cluster"
ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER="etcd1=http://192.168.8.164:2380,etcd2=http://192.168.8.141:2380"
ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE="new"
ETCD_DATA_DIR="/var/lib/etcd"
ETCD_ELECTION_TIMEOUT="10000"
ETCD_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL="2000"
ETCD_INITIAL_ELECTION_TICK_ADVANCE="false"
ETCD_ENABLE_V2="true"


How can I fix this? I've faced this issue several times back then (couldn't fix)

Fixed by removing /var/lib/postgresql/11/main directory on replica server and reinitializing patroni on leader, then on replica once again
Answer source
